# Retry the Marklogic Trigger

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-10

How do we configure trigger to retry the process to a specific count. I have a trigger configured to start whenever a doc ingests and retrieves metadata and provide to an external API. But I want it to retry several times before it fails.

Answer (score 2):

You can't specify recursion depth for a single trigger unfortunately. Each insert/update is seen separately. You can only allow or disallow recursion.

There are plenty alternatives though. You could give your trigger more time, and do multiple attempts inside one trigger call. That allows doing some sleeping in between too.

Another option is to allow trigger recursion, and keep track of counter state somewhere. Maybe inside the document (in envelope header for instance), maybe inside document metadata. You could even do it with collections like attempt-1, attempt-2.

Personally, I think just doing multiple attempts in one trigger call is simplest.

HTH!

Comment: Agreed, you could use try/catch with retry logic inside of the trigger: https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/xquery/enhanced#id_34280